# Extract the mac address from the string in java

Tags: java

Here the example,
`String test = "  link/ether 00:0c:29:d1:86:4e brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff";

00:0c:29:d1:86:4e is MacAddress.
How should I extract MacAddress and The position of MacAddress is not static?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Also give in what you tried.

Comment: what? Can you be more specific?

Comment: Also paste code snippet what you have tried so far.

Comment: Trim and Split your string by whitespace. then the [1] position should give the desired output. Try to write code yourself!

Comment: I didn't try I just want the optimum solution for that. Position 1 also doesn't provide a desirable solution.

Comment: (([A-fa-f0-9]{2}):{1}([A-Fa-f0-9]{2}):?){3} This is the regex to extract `00:0c:29:d1:86:`. Find the index of this expression.

Comment: try my solution which finds a pattern for only mac address.

Comment: @SHAHAKASH It's working fine.

Answer (score 2):

```
String test = "  link/ether 00:0c:29:d1:86:4e brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff";
String[] tokenizeString = (test.trim()).split(" ");
System.out.println(tokenizeString[1]); //From question you are intrested on this stuff only
```

I see this will solve your problem!!!

Comment: This does not give the correct result though. You can try it

Comment: Ohh I have updated my answer, forgot first part. Thank u @molamk

Comment: Actually, I tried, It gives an empty string. Have you checked your index?

Comment: @Mr.Nagar try now with updated answer

Answer (score 1):

1. **Use [String.trim](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#trim())** to remove unecessary spaces at the start and end of the string
2. **Use [String.split](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String))** to cut your string based on a delimiter. Here it's the space character
3. **Print the 2nd** item (`index 1`) to get your mac address

---

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String test = "  link/ether 00:0c:29:d1:86:4e brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff";
    String mac = test.trim().split(" ")[1];
    System.out.println(mac);
}
```

Comment: thanks for brief explanation, i liked it.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be:

```
String test = " link/ether 00:0c:29:d1:86:4e brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff";
String mac = test.substring(13, 30);
```

But this requires that the test string has always the same pattern.

Answer (score 0):

This will take care of arbitrary number of characters around the mac address:

```
String test = "  link/ether 00:0c:29:d1:86:4e brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff";
String mac = null;
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("((\\w{2}:){5}\\w{2})").matcher(test);
if (m.find()) {
    mac = m.group();
}
System.out.println(mac);
```

**Output**

```
00:0c:29:d1:86:4e
```

`\\w` can be replaced by `[a-fA-F0-9]` if you want to exclude rest of the alphabets and underscore.

Answer (score 0):

String manipulations or any other data structures are best solved either by using internal methods provided by the class which as stated in other answers can be achieved. The sequence I usually go with:
**First Approach**
`trim()`: trim trailing and leading spaces to cleanse the string
`split()`: splitting the string with a given delimiter which in this case is a space character. ASCII code 32.

**Second Approach**
Java Util package has some options that you can explore.
`java.util`: classes- StringTokenizer
`java.util.regex`: classes- Pattern and Matcher
Given your problem context and scope, you can either of these to come up with the solution. Although these classes require some best practices to work with them which you can look up or given in other short answers here.

**Third Approach**
Use third party libraries to solve problems with you. Some care has to be taken while using TPL like active use, community, testing, licensing etc. Apache and Google leads in data structures and domain and one such library you can use is [Apache Commons Lang](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html)